# 'key' is not defined no-undef setState ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

```
export default class Home extends Component {  
 state  = {
        items : [ { text: 'Buy grocery', done: true},
{ text: 'Play guitar', done: false},
{ text: 'Romantic dinner', done: false}
]
}
onItemClick  = () =>{ 
 this.setState(    
    prevState => ({
        items: prevState.items.map(
      el => el.key === key? { ...el, done: true }: el
        )

      })
  )
}
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
            <h1>
                Home Page
            </h1>
            <TodoList items={this.state.items} clickAction={this.onItemClick} />
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
export default class TodoList extends Component {

    render() {
       const itemlist = this.props.items.map((item, index) =>{
        return <div key={index}>  
        <h4 onClick={this.props.clickAction}>  {item.text + " " + item.done}</h4>  </div>
     })
        return (
            <Fragment>
            <h5>
            TodoList Page
            </h5>
            <section>
            {itemlist}
        </section>
        </Fragment>
        )
    }

}
```

I want to update a single object property inside the array. onItemClick function, which should be called when user clicks an item in the list, if the item is marked "false" as done. Otherwise the onItemClick should not be called and the click event itself should not be propagated further.
getting error 
'key' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this:

```
  el => el.key === key? { ...el, done: true }: el
```

you comapre `el.key` to `key` but the variable `key` is never defined

Comment: Thanks Simon...
Could you please explain how to pass key from Todolist component to home component

Comment: Something like onClick={key => this.props.clickAction(key)} and then you function should take key as argument like this: onItemClick  = (key) =>{...

Comment: Tried... it didn't work...
console.log(key)  gives result....
Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: h4, …}